# How replace two php

Tags: php, html, button

I creating web application. On one side I have some HTML code with 2 buttons

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default">A</button>
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default">B</button>
</div>
```

Under this HTML I calling php file.

```
<?php include("a.php"); ?>

<?php include("b.php"); ?>
```

I need call at same time only one php code. I need something like that I will clicking on these buttons and it include b.php instead a.php
When I click on A , it call a.php and when I click on B it call b.php.

These php files contains 2 different tables with data.

Thank you :)

Comment: You have to know..., there is server side here and on the other side of the river there is client side and between these two there is a big difference!

Comment: Use a conditional statement

Comment: include `a.php` and `b.php` into their own divs, and show/hide them with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve what you want:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" name="button" value="a" class="btn btn-default">A</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" value="b" class="btn btn-default">B</button>
    </div>
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
        if ($_POST['button'] == 'a') {
            include 'a.php';
        } else {
            include 'b.php';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Not working for me. :(
This nothing do. No table show.